# Generate Report of Crystal in PDF...How open in new tab or page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pdf, crystal-reports

I did a code to generate a report of Crystal Reports in PDF...But it opens in the same page of the user did a search and clicked in the button...Have any ways to open the PDF in a new tab or page ?

My code is:

```
private void OpenPDF()
{
    ReportDocument Rel = new ReportDocument();
    Rel.Load(Server.MapPath("../Reports/Test.rpt"));
    BinaryReader stream = new BinaryReader(Rel.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat));
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(stream.BaseStream.Length)));
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close(); 
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In its most simplest interpretation, to open a new window or tab, the hyperlink to the page should have the `target` attribute set to `"_blank"`.

```
<a href="GeneratePDF.aspx" target="_blank">Link to open PDF in new window</a>
```

Or you could create some Javascript that opens a new window instead. Make sure you call the Javascript function somewhere on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadPDF() {
   window.open('GeneratePDF.aspx','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');
}
</script>
```

Or this code will inform the web browser that the file is a download (rather than a page to view inside the browser window). I think this is the best approach because the user gets the choice of Opening or Saving the PDF. So this does not do what you're asking for, but you might think it's better.

```
private void OpenPDF(string downloadAsFilename)
{
    ReportDocument Rel = new ReportDocument();
    Rel.Load(Server.MapPath("../Reports/Test.rpt"));
    BinaryReader stream = new BinaryReader(Rel.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat));
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + downloadAsFilename);
    Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.BaseStream.Length.ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(stream.BaseStream.Length)));
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write this code on button ::: OnClientClick="target = '_blank';"