# How can i show doc,docx and pdf files's content in view in mvc4 which was in sql server as varbinary(max) datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, docx, doc

I am developing job hunting site in mvc4. Here i want to read doc,docx and pdf files's content data  which was in database as varbinary(max) datattype and show in a particular div in a view. Is there any soloution for my propblem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at these options :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6446557/2845152

http://stackoverflow.com/a/13727524/2845152

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show these documents natively in the browser. You can either offer a link to the document, which would link to a handler which outputs the document as a binary stream, or consider using a viewer to present the documents.

See this post for info on option 1:
[Generate Report of Crystal in PDF...How open in new tab or page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180418/generate-report-of-crystal-in-pdf-how-open-in-new-tab-or-page)